# Combine dataframe in python but avoid duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, df1, and df2. I am joining on two different column names. For some reason when I perform this join, the result creates exponential duplicated rows. How would I avoid this. I am using outer join.

**Data**

df1

```
ID  Date
a   1/1/2022
a   1/1/2022
b   2/1/2022
b   2/1/2022
b   2/1/2022
```

df2

```
Quarter     State
1/1/2022    ny
4/3/2023    ca
6/1/2024    ca
7/1/2021    wa
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date        Quarter     State
a   1/1/2022    1/1/2022    ny
a   1/1/2022    na          na
b   2/1/2022    na          na
b   2/1/2022    na          na
b   2/1/2022    na          na
```

**Doing**

```
join = pd.merge( df1, df2, left_on='Date', right_on='Quarter', how='outer'

)
```

However, the output is giving me much more rows than what I began with. I would think that a left join would solve this, but I am still getting duplicates. I am still researching this.Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish here? What are IDs 'a' and 'b', and what is the output table meant to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `temp` column `t` with `groupby`/`cumcount` and just use that column for the merge.

```
merged_df = (
    df1.assign(t=df1.groupby('Date').cumcount())
    .merge(
        df2.assign(t=df2.groupby('Quarter').cumcount()),
        left_on=['Date', 't'],
        right_on=['Quarter', 't'],
        how='left')
    .drop('t', 1)
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ID      Date   Quarter State
0  a  1/1/2022  1/1/2022    ny
1  a  1/1/2022       NaN   NaN
2  b  2/1/2022       NaN   NaN
3  b  2/1/2022       NaN   NaN
4  b  2/1/2022       NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you I will try. What is 't'? Is this a common issue with joins?  (duplicates?)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, a left join should do it. Simply try changing "outer" to "left" in the how argument.

```
join = pd.merge( df1, df2, left_on='Date', right_on='Quarter', how='left')
```

Comment: When I perform the left join, I get the duplicates..

Comment: This works and should probably be the accepted answer since it's the simplest fix. @Lynn, if it's not working for you, please include your dataframe definitions in the question to investigate further.

Comment: Hmm ok it is not working when I perform the above. The solution that works for me is the first answer.

Comment: @Ratler the accepted answer is correct. Basically the solution OP needs is to drop the duplicates after left join. Note that row 0 and row 1 of df1 are identical, and will thus naturally create duplicate rows after left join - OP wants to drop those as well after join.

Comment: @Mercury, you're right, I was focussing on the NaN rows and missed the duplicate first two rows!